# Can't able to add events in android calendar directly without using intents

Tags: android, events

I want to add events in android default calendar but cant able to add events. I have searched and got a solution using intents to add events in android calendar but i want to add events without using intents. how can i achieve this. Can anybody help

Comment: Google has a REST API for Calendar, but it's not trivial to set up and use this. Why would you not want to add an event via Intent? This would let the user use the Calendar app that they are already familiar with to make the event.

Comment: I have multiple events which i want to add to android calendar. I am showing a custom Calendar which will show events on particular date when user choose the date and click on sync button it will be added to android calendar directly without showing editable calendar events screen.